# More reliable loop to update ObjectID in Mongo?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I am migrating from SQL to NOSQL but still want to maintain a separate record and use ObjectIDs to link in some cases. I have this loop which works... in part.

```
router.get('/col', function(req, res, next) {
var stream = Record.find().stream();

stream.on('data', function (doc) {
    if(doc.oldcolid){
      Collection.findOne({da: doc.oldcolid}, function(err, col){
          doc.collectionId = col._id
          doc.save()
          console.log(col.name)
      })
    }


})

stream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err)
})

stream.on('close', function () {
  console.log("done")
})

});
```

However, it seems to finish and miss many records.

```
> db.records.count({collectionId: null})
12130
> db.records.count({collectionId: {$exists: true}})
5882
> db.records.count({oldcolid: {$exists: true}})
18012
```

I stored the old ID from the MySQL database in both collections to do the link. There are no obvious errors but it consistently seems to fall over. I do not seem to hit the on('close') function either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so thinking about this in reverse was simpler.

```
var stream = Collection.find().stream();
stream.on('data', function (doc) {
      console.log(doc.da)
      stream.pause()
      Record.update({oldcolid: doc.da}, {collectionId: doc._id}, { multi: true }, function (err, raw) {

          if(err) {console.log(err)}
          console.log(raw)
          stream.resume()
      })



})

stream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err)
})

stream.on('close', function () {
  console.log("done")
})
```

Fewer operations, less trouble.